# How pull closest maturity date in relation to each as of date in python using groupby

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, date, datetime

I am currently looking at a variety of future curves. Each as of-date has a list of futures curves available. My end goal is to pull the maturity date value in relation to each individual as of the date. Below is an example of my data frame

```
    asOfDate maturityDate  value
0  2017-10-02   2017-10-01  406.8
1  2017-10-02   2017-11-01  406.8
2  2017-10-02   2017-12-01  398.3
3  2017-10-02   2018-01-01  398.3
4  2017-10-02   2018-02-01  390.2
5  2017-10-02   2018-03-01  390.2
6  2017-10-02   2018-04-01  380.5
7  2017-10-02   2018-05-01  380.5
8  2017-10-02   2018-06-01  385.0
9  2017-10-02   2018-07-01  385.0
10 2017-10-02   2018-08-01  385.0
11 2017-10-02   2018-09-01  385.0
12 2017-10-02   2018-10-01  383.2
13 2017-10-02   2018-11-01  383.2
14 2017-10-03   2017-10-01  410.4
15 2017-10-03   2017-11-01  410.4
16 2017-10-03   2017-12-01  400.8
17 2017-10-03   2018-01-01  400.8
18 2017-10-03   2018-02-01  392.5
19 2017-10-03   2018-03-01  392.5
```

The end goal would be a list of the closest value of each maturityDate relative to each as of date. So given the above data set the desired output would be

```
  asOfDate maturityDate  value
0  2017-10-02   2017-10-01  406.8
14 2017-10-03   2017-10-01  410.4
```

Given that the contract closes to the asOfDate on 2017-10-02 is 2017-10-01 and 2017-10-03 closest is that same contract.

My thinking is I could do some type of groupby for each as of date, this is what I have tested thus far

```
df_lumber[df_lumber['maturityDate']==df_lumber.groupby(['asOfDate'])['maturityDate'].apply(min)]
```

I am trying to match the current maturity dates to match the smallest maturity date for each as-of date, which in theory should be what I am after.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OP is not far from the desired output.

First of all, make sure both columns are of `datetime` with [`pandas.to_datetime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html)

```
df['asOfDate'] = pd.to_datetime(df['asOfDate'])
df['maturityDate'] = pd.to_datetime(df['maturityDate'])
```

Then, this will do the work

```
df[df["maturityDate"] == df.groupby("asOfDate")["maturityDate"].transform(min)]

[Out]:
     asOfDate maturityDate  value
0  2017-10-02   2017-10-01  406.8
14 2017-10-03   2017-10-01  410.4
```

---

**Notes:**

- One is grouping by `asOfDate` with [`pandas.DataFrame.groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html).
- And for each group use `.transform('min')` to get the minimum for the column `maturityDate`.